# Find exact match in string

Tags: php, string

I want to check if exactly this string:

> "title":"New York City"

is in this *huge* string:

> {"response":[{"cid":378,"title":"New York City","area":"New York County","region":"New York"},{"cid":2211916,"title":"West New York","area":"Hudson County","region":"New Jersey"},{"cid":4907470,"title":"New York","area":"Caldwell County","region":"Missouri"},{"cid":4910556,"title":"Little New York","area":"Marshall County","region":"Alabama"},{"cid":4923978,"title":"New York","area":"Santa Rosa County","region":"Florida"},{"cid":4944119,"title":"New York","area":"Ballard County","region":"Kentucky"},{"cid":4963231,"title":"Township of New York","area":"Caldwell County","region":"Missouri"},{"cid":5004855,"title":"Little New York","area":"Gonzales County","region":"Texas"},{"cid":5005637,"title":"New York","area":"Henderson County","region":"Texas"},{"cid":5022669,"title":"New York","area":"Wayne County","region":"Iowa"},{"cid":5046761,"title":"New York Mills","area":"Otter Tail County","region":"Minnesota"},{"cid":5052155,"title":"Township of New York","area":"York County","region":"Nebraska"},{"cid":5056268,"title":"Town of West New York","area":"Hudson County","region":"New Jersey"},{"cid":5058154,"title":"East New York","area":"Kings County","region":"New York"},{"cid":5060715,"title":"New York Mills","area":"Oneida County","region":"New York"},{"cid":5098755,"title":"New York","area":"Cibola County","region":"New Mexico"},{"cid":5109737,"title":"New York Mining District","area":"Elko County","region":"Nevada"}]}

I tried with **strpos()**, but I got all these results.

EDIT: 
Here's the code:

```
 $question = "\"title\"" . ":" . "\"$city\"";

 if(preg_match("~\b$question\b~", $cities)) {
    flag = 1;
}
```

where *cities* is this *huge* string above, and *city* is New York City.

Comment: Can you please show your codes?

Comment: I don't know php, but typically there is a find function to use in a language. If not, you can make your own. They are not that hard to make.

Comment: Why don't you [decode that json object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and search it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *huge string* is actually a json string, which you can parse using `json_decode()`function.

Reference:

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

And I believe you're trying to search *New York City* in the title property of your json string, which you can do like this:

```
// here $json is your json string
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
$string_to_search = "New York City";

$found = false;
for($i = 0; $i < count($json_array['response']); ++$i){
    if($json_array['response'][$i]['title'] == $string_to_search){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found){
    // string exists
}else{
    // string doesn't exists
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed. Didn't know that was json string, so I was trying to search it with PHP preg_match. Thank you for your time!